# MySQL select a set of columns with more than one variation in another column

Tags: mysql

table looks like this:

```
id group name
1  1     A
2  1     A
3  2     A
4  2     B
5  3     A
```

I want to select the rows with more than one distinct names in the same group. The result should be the following:

```
id group name
3  2     A
4  2     B
```

Any idea how do achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the groups with aggregation:

```
select group
from t
group by group
having min(name) <> max(name);
```

You can get the original rows using `join`, `in`, or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.group in (select group
                  from t
                  group by group
                  having min(name) <> max(name)
                 );
```

Note: `group` is a lousy name for a column because it is a SQL keyword and a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: I agree. it's a column name i made up for this question. I'm not using this name in the real database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group, t1.name
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable t2 
    WHERE t2.group=t1.group AND t2.name <> t1.name
);
```

Or you could do it by counting distinct names in the group:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group, t2.name
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2.group FROM mytable AS t2
    GROUP BY t2.group HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.name) > 1
) AS t2 USING (group);
```